# C# Dictionary large performance hit when key is struct

Tags: c#

I am writing a class that allows for two different indexes with the goal of O(1) lookup for each. Both indexes are currently using `Dictionary` as the underlying structure.

```
internal class RayCollection
{

  private readonly Dictionary<ulong, Ray> idLookup_;
  private readonly Dictionary<ProjectionKey, Ray> projectionLookup_;

  public RayCollection()
  {
    idLookup_ = new Dictionary<ulong, Ray>();
    projectionLookup_ = new Dictionary<ProjectionKey, Ray>();
  }

  public void Add(Ray ray)
  {
    idLookup_.Add(ray.Id, ray);
    projectionLookup_.Add(new ProjectionKey(ray.From, ray.To), ray);
  }

  public Ray this[ulong id]
  {
    get => idLookup_[id];
  }

  public Ray this[ulong from, ulong to]
  {
    get => projectionLookup_[new ProjectionKey(from, to) ];
  }

  internal struct ProjectionKey
  {
    ulong From;
    ulong To;

    public ProjectionKey(ulong from, ulong to)
    {
      From = from;
      To = to;
    }
  }

}
```

This works as it should, but the performance hit from using a struct is enormous! Indexing with `ProjectionKey` is almost 130x slower.

```
           Method |       Mean |      Error |     StdDev |
----------------- |-----------:|-----------:|-----------:|
         GetViaId |   5.823 ns |  0.1801 ns |  0.1769 ns |
 GetViaProjection | 646.951 ns | 12.4307 ns | 12.2086 ns |
```

A fair amount of this overhead is probably caused by having to create a new instance of `ProjectionKey` every time the index operator is called, and I presume more overhead is caused by `Dictionary` having to hash the struct to perform the lookup. In either case, I would like to decrease this overhead as much as possible.

So then, my questions are:

- For `this[ulong from, ulong to]`, is there a way I can implicitly treat `from` and `to` as a struct without having to allocate it? It seems silly to instantiate a new struct when the variables are adjacent to each other on the stack.
- Is there a better way to approach this, considering a fair amount of overhead is likely being caused by `Dictionary` hashing the struct

And one last thing: Before any "premature optimization" or "is this actually affecting your performance" posts, yes, I do realize this. I use opportunities like these to better understand C# and .NET from a low level perspective and believe extreme optimization cases like these provide good knowledge.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1341 and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2018/07/17/performance-implications-of-default-struct-equality-in-c/ may be of interest.

Comment: The short version is because it is using the built in GetHashCode and Equals function which is not the best, if you used your own implementation it would likely work faster.

Comment: Make the key a string : From.ToString() + "^" + To.ToString()